# Spring Boot: How to schedule and execute tasks concurrently?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

What I want to is as follows:

- In a Spring Boot application,
- Schedule tasks (functions, or a method of a class) with cron expressions (cron expressions can be different for each task).
- When it's time to run task, run it, concurrently with other task if neccessary (start time is the same, running periods overlaps etc.) - and without any limitation of the concurrency.
- The tasks can take several minutes.
- The number of tasks (and its options) and cron expressions cannot be determined at development time. It is end user configurable.

The scheduler must satisfy the following requirements.

- It must not have a wait queue. if a scheduled time arrives, the task must be executed immediately (Don't worry about the number of the threads).
- When the tasks are not running, the number of idle threads should be minimal - or the number should be controllable.

I've looked at ThreadPoolTaskScheduler, but it seems that it fails to satisfy the above requirements.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` fail to satisfy that. Also you have to make a seperation between scheduling and running, the `TaskScheduler` is for scheduling and you could use a `TaskExecutor` for the running (by using `@Async`). If you know the number of concurrent tasks (as you need someway to confiugre them) you can also configure either the `TaskScheduler` or the `TaskExecutor` to have the proper amount of maximum threads available.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. I use @Async several other places, and I don't want to share `TaskExecutor` with this feature. And maybe it will not be easy to cancel it if the task 'escapes' the scheduler by @Async. The number of concurrent tasks changes as users add or delete tasks, so there is no maximum number of threads.

Comment: @M.Deinum Maybe I should instantiate a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler for each task... It seems foolish, but it should work anyway.

Comment: Yes there is a number of max tasks that is the number of maximum task that run in a period (or the number os task prepared by the client). Which you know at runtime so you cna use that to (dynamically) size the number of threads. You can just inject your `TaskScheduler` and call the `schedule` method of your liking to schedule tasks. Instead of only focussing on `@Scheduled` I suggest you start reading about the underlying infrastructure. And you do want to keep the number of threads under control, each thread eats memory, which eventually will lead to memory errors or concurrency issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you! Calling `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize()` at runtime according to the number of tasks, and calling `scheduler.getScheduledThreadPoolExecutor()`'s `setKeepAliveTime()` and `allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)` satisfies the requirement. Since I manually instantiate ThreadPoolTaskScheduler, calling the methods are easy.

Comment: You don't want to set the core pool size but the max pool size. That way it will scale down when not all threads are needed.

Comment: @M.Deinum In the source code of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` which is used by `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, it says:  "While this class inherits from `ThreadPoolExecutor`, a few of the inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, because it acts as a fixed-sized pool using `corePoolSize` threads and an unbounded queue, adjustments `maximumPoolSize` have no useful effect."

Comment: @M.Deinum Also it says: "Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set `corePoolSize` to zero or use `allowCoreThreadTimeOut` because this may leave the pool without threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run." But maybe I can live with it...

Comment: Well as stated you want to control the created threads, and hence my initial suggestion to take apart the scheduling and the execution. WIth the latter you can simply use a min/max thread pool which will scale down (which is one of your requirements).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you. I'll think of it. Also, with `@Async("executorForMyScheduler")`, I can separate other async functions with this feature.